# ConfigureApplicationCookie loginPath no longer respected after changing default policy

Tags: asp.net-identity, .net-5

I have an .NET 5 application that uses Identity as the primary login for users. I also have a series of API endpoints that require outside access so these are protected by a JWT token ("xx.xx.api") Authentication scheme. All of this works fine.

I wanted to have the internal endpoints to be able to respond to postman requests without having to login through the identity part of the application. So I have created a seperate JWT token (xxxxx.postman) that our internal postman can utilize. I have created a Policy through the "AuthorizationPolicyBuilder" that requires either a role or a specific claim, which is now my default policy. Everything apart from the "LoginPath"/"AccessDenied" set through the ConfigureApplicationCookie" seems to work after this change, the login cookie responds to changes to the timeout, but I cannot get these two to work with the new multi policy scheme.

Before the change, this code works and redirects users correctly to the login page, if they are Unauthenticated.

```
services.AddAuthorization(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddPolicy("xxxxx", opt => opt.RequireClaim("xxxxxxxClaim", "xx.xx.api"));
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

            options.LoginPath = "/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

With the new Scheme in place, the application no longer redirects the unauthenticated user.

```
var multiSchemePolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
                JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
              .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
              .RequireAssertion(assert =>
                assert.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "xxxxxxxClaim" && claim.Value == "xxxxx.postman") ||
                assert.User.IsInRole("yyyyyyyyy"))
              .Build();

        services.AddAuthorization(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.DefaultPolicy = multiSchemePolicy;
            cfg.AddPolicy("xxxxx", opt => opt.RequireClaim("xxxxxxxxClaim", "xx.xx.api"));
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

            options.LoginPath = "/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

I have found that I can make it work again by setting

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                response.Redirect("/login");
               }
        });
```

Not that it explains why the ConfigureApplicationCookie LoginPath is nolonger respected.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could explain why this happens and whether or not my workaround is sound. Thanks!

Comment: Am facing the same issue, did you by any chance found out what was wrong

Comment: Hi there,
Sorry for the belated answer, I didn't find the root cause, but opted to go for the solution provided below, as it "fixed" the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to answer my own question as this fixes the problem.

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                response.Redirect("/login");
               }
        });
```